# Proof of the linear momentum for two-dimensional PDE (Klein-Gordon equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Proof of the linear momentum for two-dimensional PDE (Klein-Gordon equation)
\begin{align}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}+F\left(u\right)=0\ ,\ -\infty<x<\infty\ ,t\geq0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
u\left(x,0\right)=f\left(x\right)\ ,\ u_t\left(x,0\right)=g\left(x\right)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\left|u_t\right|,\left|u_x\right|\rightarrow0\ as\ \left|x\right|\rightarrow\infty
\end{align}
\begin{align}
P\left(t\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(u_tu_x\right)dx=constant=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(g\left(x\right)f^\prime\left(x\right)\right)dx=\ P\left(0\right) 
\end{align}
Where $F\left(u\right)=G^\prime\left(u\right)$

I started with multiplying the equation by $u_x$
\begin{align}
u_xu_{tt}-u_xu_{xx}+u_xF\left(u\right)=0
\end{align}
Adding and subtracting $u_t u_xt$  , then I converted it to partial form
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(u_xu_t\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{u_t^2}{2}+\frac{u_x^2}{2}-G\left(u\right)\right)
\end{align}
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(u_tu_x\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{u_t^2}{2}+\frac{u_x^2}{2}-G\left(u\right)\right)dx}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(u_tu_x\right)dx=0+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-G\left(u\right)\right)dx}
\end{align}
Where $G(u)$  is polynomial in terms of u.

My first question: I know $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-G\left(u\right)\right)dx}\ =0$  but how we got that?

Now,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(u_tu_x\right)dx=0
\end{align}
Then I got
\begin{align}
P\left(t\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(u_tu_x\right)dx=constant=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(g\left(x\right)f^\prime\left(x\right)\right)dx=\ P\left(0\right)
\end{align}

My second question: Is my proof true or there is another method to proof that ?